# Serial communication between Arduino and Java NetBeans

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, java

I am new to this serial communication between Arduino and Java NetBeans.
I am doing some small project and I need to get data from external EEPROM 24LC256 which is connected to Arduino UNO and pass it to the Java NetBeans platform not the Eclipse. So far I am using RXTX driver to communicate with Arduino in Java and easily get the data from serial monitor of Arduino IDE.

So can anyone help me, on how can I serially communicate with this external EEPROM using Java?

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.util.Enumeration; 

public class last extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener  {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "COM3", // Windows
    };
    private BufferedReader input;  
    private OutputStream output;   /** The output stream to the port */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000; /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;  /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {   //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }
        try {          // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), TIME_OUT);
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,  // set port parameters
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));   // open the streams
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);   // add event listeners
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }}

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {                      
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }}

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println("the state of the led is  "+inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        last main = new last();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() { //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

This is the code in Java NetBeans.

Comment: Perhaps you can attach your code for higher rate of getting a proper answer. Just a wild guess, have you try softserial?

Comment: here i wrote code

Answer (score 2):

Your EEPROM has I2C interface, so first you shall program Arduino to access it: [An I2C EEPROM Class for Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryForI2CEEPROM)

Then implement some kind of communication protocol over serial, to send commands instructing Arduino to read/write from EEPROM. For example, with following commands:

- for writing `write:<address>,<count>,<data_as_hex_string>`
- for reading `read:<address>,<count>`
- response for reading: `<address>,<count>,<data_as_hex_string>`